# Compiling haskell from haskell

Tags: haskell, compilation, ghc

So I have a haskell program where I do some formatting to a haskell source file and then I want to call the GHC to compile said file, can anyone tell how can I do that?

In case this helps, this is the program I'm making, it's just a emoji code haskell parser:

```
module EmojiParser where

import Prelude hiding (writeFile, readFile)  
import Data.Char
import Data.Text (pack, unpack)
import Path.Text.UTF8 (readFile, writeFile)
import Path.Internal

transpile filePath = do content <- readFile $ Path filePath
                        writeFile (Path filePath) . pack . parseEmoji . unpack $ content                       

parseEmoji :: [Char] -> [Char]
parseEmoji = foldl (++) "" . map f 
  where 
    minEmoji = 128511
    maxEmoji = 128592
    f x = let cval = ord x
          in if cval > minEmoji && cval < maxEmoji 
             then "emoji_symbol_" ++ (show cval) 
             else [x]
```

Comment: While this is possible, I seriously doubt that it's a sensible approach to whatever problem your tackling here. Can you give some context?

Comment: Hum Im' just turning emoji written haskell into compilable haskell, but I wanted to compile it too.

Comment: You can define Unicode characters, including emoji, as operators and function names in standard Haskell.  See for example the Unicode Prelude: https://hackage.haskell.org/package/unicode-prelude

Comment: yah but it's for the fun of doing it myself, thanks for the info :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example from the ghc user guide:
https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/master/users-guide/extending_ghc.html#using-ghc-as-a-library

```
import GHC
import GHC.Paths ( libdir )
import DynFlags ( defaultLogAction )

main =
    defaultErrorHandler defaultLogAction $ do
      runGhc (Just libdir) $ do
        dflags <- getSessionDynFlags
        setSessionDynFlags dflags
        target <- guessTarget "test_main.hs" Nothing
        setTargets [target]
        load LoadAllTargets
```

with that you should be able to do this:

```
$ cat test_main.hs
main = putStrLn "hi"
$ ghc -package ghc simple_ghc_api.hs
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( simple_ghc_api.hs, simple_ghc_api.o )
Linking simple_ghc_api ...
$ ./simple_ghc_api
$ ./test_main
hi
$
```

Once it works for you like that, it should be easy for you to include it in you program.

Comment: don't forget to accept and upgrade the answer then ;)